# Python3 No Module Named Config

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When running python3 app.py I get error:

```
File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Config import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Config'
```

Here's the contents of app.py:

```
'<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" /></cross-domain-policy>'
import logging, sys, json, os, signal, logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from colorlog import ColoredFormatter
from Config import config
from Utils.EventManeger import EventHandler
#from Handlers import Login
from Engine.Engine import CJSnowFactory
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, task
from twisted.python import log



log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
def InitiateColorLogger(name='cjsnow'):

    cjsnow_logger = logging.getLogger("cjsnow")

    cjsnow_stream = logging.StreamHandler()

    LogFormat = "  %(reset)s%(log_color)s%(levelname)-8s%(reset)s | %(log_color)s%(message)s"
    cjsnow_stream.setFormatter(ColoredFormatter(LogFormat, log_colors={
        'DEBUG': 'white',
        'INFO': 'cyan',
        'WARNING': 'yellow',
        'ERROR': 'red',
        'CRITICAL': 'black,bg_red',
        'TAG': 'white',
    }))
    cjsnow_logger.addHandler(cjsnow_stream)

    cjsnow_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return cjsnow_logger

CjsnowLogger = InitiateColorLogger()
logger = logging.getLogger("cjsnow")
def onExitSignal(*a):
    logger.warning("closing?")
    if not reactor.running:
        os._exit(1)
    else:
        reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)

for sig in (signal.SIGABRT, signal.SIGILL, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGSEGV, signal.SIGTERM):
    signal.signal(sig, onExitSignal)

server = CJSnowFactory(server="Login")
server.start()
```

I have already tried:
`pip3 install Config`

python3 --version: `Python 3.6.9`

pip3 --version: `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`

Other files refer to the config - here is the github page for them if that helps: https://github.com/klabacher/Tusk - so editing the config lines out isn't an option.

Comment: Are you sure the module is called "Config" and not "config"? Module names are usually lower case.

Comment: I also tried changing that, same error.

Comment: ... So you don't know what the module you're trying to import is called? It certainly seems like you don't have it installed then.

Comment: Your code doesn't even appear to use config, so you may be able to remove or comment out that line.

Comment: shall add an edit

Comment: Probably Config is a file that the programmer didn't include in the github repository.

Comment: The config file has been [added to the repo](https://github.com/klabacher/Tusk/commit/f93bdaf435ca6e1443a6f7b37e66ac8948f81a10) now, so you should probably pull it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config is not a module, it's a python file that is missing from this github repository.

If you go into the repository's `.gitignore`, you can see `Config.py` in the last line.

Comment: The repo owner has subsequently [added the config file to the repo](https://github.com/klabacher/Tusk/commit/f93bdaf435ca6e1443a6f7b37e66ac8948f81a10).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have to install the config module using the following command on the terminal

pip3 install config

and reload the code editor if it doesn't correct the error

Comment: Henrique's answer says that this is not the issue.